# Order the entries including NA of all columns on a dataframe in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a dataframe and I want to order its order for each column in ascending way and put the NA on the last rows. I have done this but there is a slight error there

```
a<-c(5,1,0,3,2,0.6,1.6,7,9,0)
b<-c(11,0,1,18,11,11,0,13,20,10)
c<-c(10,20,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.4,0,0.9,1,1)

MAT <- cbind(a,b,c)
MAT <- apply(MAT, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 5, "YES", "NO"))

for (i in 1:nrow(MAT)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(MAT)){
    if (MAT[i, j]== "YES"){
      MAT[i,j] = i
    } else {
      MAT[i,j] = NA
      }
    }
  }
  for (j in 1:ncol(MAT)){
    MAT[,j] = sort(MAT[,j], na.last = TRUE)
  }
print(MAT)

      a   b    c  
[1,] "8" "1"  "1"
[2,] "9" "10" "2"
[3,] NA  "4"  NA 
[4,] NA  "5"  NA 
[5,] NA  "6"  NA 
[6,] NA  "8"  NA 
[7,] NA  "9"  NA 
[8,] NA  NA   NA 
[9,] NA  NA   NA 
[10,] NA  NA   NA
```

The row 2 col b entries, the number 10 should be the on the row 7 col b such that b = (1,4,5,6,8,9,10, NA, NA, NA). Why is it happening? How to make it right or better if there is a simpler code doing this please?

Comment: Change the line `MAT[,j] = sort(MAT[,j], na.last = TRUE)` to `MAT[,j] = sort(as.numeric(MAT[,j]), na.last = TRUE)`

Comment: @GKi That changes all entries (including NA) to numeric right? But I do not understand why is it different from mine when they were ordered correctly for the other two columns?

Comment: When you sort a string, `10` is before `2`. The other are correct because they have only one digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way might be:

```
a <- c(5,1,0,3,2,0.6,1.6,7,9,0)
b <- c(11,0,1,18,11,11,0,13,20,10)
c <- c(10,20,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.4,0,0.9,1,1)
MAT <- cbind(a,b,c)

apply(`[<-`(row(MAT), MAT<=5, NA), 2, sort, na.last = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    8    1    1
# [2,]    9    4    2
# [3,]   NA    5   NA
# [4,]   NA    6   NA
# [5,]   NA    8   NA
# [6,]   NA    9   NA
# [7,]   NA   10   NA
# [8,]   NA   NA   NA
# [9,]   NA   NA   NA
#[10,]   NA   NA   NA
```

or

```
sapply(apply(MAT>5, 2, which, simplify = FALSE), `[`, 1:nrow(MAT))
#       a  b  c
# [1,]  8  1  1
# [2,]  9  4  2
# [3,] NA  5 NA
# [4,] NA  6 NA
# [5,] NA  8 NA
# [6,] NA  9 NA
# [7,] NA 10 NA
# [8,] NA NA NA
# [9,] NA NA NA
#[10,] NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```r
MAT <- cbind(a, b, c)
apply(MAT, 2, function(z) {
  ind <- which(z > 5)
  c(ind, rep(NA, length(z) - length(ind)))
})
#        a  b  c
#  [1,]  8  1  1
#  [2,]  9  4  2
#  [3,] NA  5 NA
#  [4,] NA  6 NA
#  [5,] NA  8 NA
#  [6,] NA  9 NA
#  [7,] NA 10 NA
#  [8,] NA NA NA
#  [9,] NA NA NA
# [10,] NA NA NA
```

Notes:

- if you need `character`, you can replace `ind` with `as.character(ind)`;
- the reason your `"10"` was coming before `"4"` is that you are sorting strings, and `10 < 4` is different from `"10" < "4"`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit absurd, but you could use nested `apply` functions:

```r
apply(
  t(
    sapply(
      seq_len(nrow(MAT)), 
      # function(i) NA_real_^((MAT[i, ] > 5) - 1) * (MAT[i, ] > 5) * i
      function(i) ifelse(MAT[i, ] > 5, (MAT[i, ] > 5) * i, NA_real_)
      )
    ),
  2,
  sort, 
  na.last = TRUE
  )
```

This returns

```r
       a  b  c
 [1,]  8  1  1
 [2,]  9  4  2
 [3,] NA  5 NA
 [4,] NA  6 NA
 [5,] NA  8 NA
 [6,] NA  9 NA
 [7,] NA 10 NA
 [8,] NA NA NA
 [9,] NA NA NA
[10,] NA NA NA
```